# How to find a the partial derivative of a function that includes functions as inputs

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Take $f(x,g(x)) = x \cdot g(x)$. where $g(x) = x^2$

The solution we're going to want to find is $3x^2$ but I'm having a hard time finding the general way of writing it...

I looked [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx)

And I thoght it that would be doing something like this
$D_x [f(x,g(x))] = D_xf(x) + D_xg(x) = g(x) + 2x = x^2 + 2x$

But that's wrong... I know it's a simple question but for some reason I'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $\phi(x) = f(x, g(x))$, with $f(x, y) = xy$ and $g(x) = x^2$.
Then $\phi'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x)) g'(x)$.

Comment: Mind if I ask a follow up for why I asked? I'm trying to see why the derivative with respect to $p$ of $v(p,e(p,u))$ is $D_p v(p,e(p,u))+ D_w v(p,e)h(p,u)$ where the derivative of $e(p,u)$ with respect to $p$ is $h(p,u)$. It looks more like a full derivative to me but I think it's only supposed to be the derivative with respect to $p$

Comment: You're right: we take the total derivative of $x \mapsto f(x, g(x))$ wrt $x$. This is the sum of the direct effect of $x$ on $f$ and the indirect effect of $x$ on $f$ through $g$.  
Write down what $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $g'(x)$ are, and you'll get the correct result $3x^2$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I'm almost there but still a little short, with my simple example let's do $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x)) g'(x)$.  Is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x))$ supposed to be seen as the derivative of $xy$ with respect to $x$ which is $y = x^2$ and then the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x)) g'(x)$ supposed to be seen as the derivative of $xy \cdot 2x$ with respect to y which evaluates to $2x^2$. Together that would get us the right answer $3x^2$ but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to think about it yet

Comment: No, it's a multiplication: $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))) \times g'(x)$.